# Shortest way to merge DataTables and remove all duplicate rows

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, merge, duplicates

At first i would like to say that i know there are many examples with merging and duplicates but i couldnt find an exact answer to my question. Currently im getting results that i want (using loops) but i was just wondering if it can be done using LINQ or maybe other (shorter) way.

Following are the items in first table:

[image: table1]

...and second table:

[image: table2]

What i would like to achieve is to compare values in two columns in these tables: Column A and Column C  and get rows from second table (with additional value of column B in first table) which are not duplicated in first table. So in this particular case.. something like that:

[image]

Comment: you could have posted code with loops that you did, may be any one of us could have shortened it !

Comment: on your tables is Column A have the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

This works as long as the first table "Column A" is unique, which I assume has to be if you want the value from "Column B".  If not this could fail and would have to write the linq statement differently and have to know what you would want for "Column B" in a many to many relationship.

```
var dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof (string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof (string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof (int));
dt1.Rows.Add("XYZ", "s54a4", 1);
dt1.Rows.Add("QWE", "g743s", 2);
dt1.Rows.Add("ABC", "j74ss", 2);

var dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof (string));
dt2.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof (int));
dt2.Columns.Add("Column Z", typeof (string));
dt2.Rows.Add("XYZ", 1, "something1");
dt2.Rows.Add("QWE", 2, "something2");
dt2.Rows.Add("ABC", 4, "something3");

var dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof (string));
dt3.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof (int));
dt3.Columns.Add("Column Z", typeof (string));
dt3.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof (string));


// Assumes value in Column A in dt1 is unique
// Joins on Column A between the two tables then filters where column C isn't the same
var data = from dataRow1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
           join dataRow2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on dataRow1.Field<string>("Column A") equals
               dataRow2.Field<string>("Column A")
           where dataRow1.Field<int>("Column C") != dataRow2.Field<int>("Column C")
           select
               new[]
                   {dataRow2["Column A"], dataRow2["Column C"], dataRow2["Column Z"], dataRow1["Column B"]};

// add the results into dt3
foreach (var d in data)
{
    dt3.Rows.Add(d);
}
```